# running matlab functions using bash terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, matlab, functions

I had a problem running matlab functions straight from bash terminal on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001183/how-to-call-matlab-functions-from-the-linux-command-line) suggestions but they didn't work. Below I offer my solution.

Comment: If you have a solution, post it as an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you better run scripts, not functions, otherwise you can't exit back to bash, you remain with a matlab terminal open. Second, to run a function anyway, you write a file with the function in it, and run that as a script. here is an example:

```
echo "myFunction([],'some_text',95:99)" > tmp.m
matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "tmp;exit"
```

you can later remove the tmp.m file with rm tmp.m when you are done. I hope it saves time for future matlab users on Ubuntu